# What should be the prop type of passing a variable down in a child component via function

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Given the following component:

```js
Component.propTypes = {
  // not right:
  children: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node),
    PropTypes.node,
  ]),
}

export default function Component({ children }) {
  return children({ someValue: "foobar" });
}
```

```js
AnotherComponent.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string,
}

export default function AnotherComponent({ value }) {
  return <p>{value}</p>
}
```

Used like:

```js
<Component>
 {(someValue) => (<AnotherComponent value={someValue} />)}
</Component>
```

Gives the error: `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'children' supplied to 'Component'.`

What is the proptype for this?

Comment: As I can see your someValue is `foobar` which is string, so it should be `PropTypes.string`

Comment: yes, but where?

Comment: in `AnotherComponent.propTypes`

Comment: The 'AnotherComponent' is working fine. However, Component itself is giving the error: `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `Component`.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `PropTypes.func`:

```
Component.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func
};
```

[image: Edit great-bird-qusxk]

As for "real-life" example, you can check the [`children` type of `AutoSizer`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/AutoSizer.md) [[2]](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-auto-sizer/blob/master/src/index.js)

Comment: Can I also define what the returned object would look like for that function? (thanks for the AutoSizer link, I'll check it out)

Comment: It looks like that I should use either Typescript or a custom validator... Was hoping there was a default method in the 'prop-types' package. I.E. `children: (someType) => PropTypes.node`

Comment: Yes, you can see an example: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized-auto-sizer/blob/master/src/index.js